# Field will not populate in hash table

Tags: powershell, csv

```
import-csv c:\temp\aduserimport.csv |
Select-Object -property *,
          @{ name = 'SamAccountName'; expression = { $_.Login } },
          @{ Label = 'Name'; expression = { $_.login } },
          @{ Label = 'Department'; expression= { $_Dept }}
```

The csv file looks like this.  It shows the DEPT instead of the Department value.  The Login should not be there either.  It also show What am I doing wrong?

> login,dept,city,title
>
> Jimmy Jawn,it,philadelphia,president

Yet my results look like this

> login          : Jimmy Jawn
>
> dept           : it
>
> city           : philadelphia
>
> title          : president
>
> SamAccountName : Jimmy Jawn
>
> Name           : Jimmy Jawn
>
> Department     :

Comment: In the last line there is a dot missing `$_Dept` => `$_.Dept` The width may exceed your screen width, append `|Format-Table -Auto` to the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

helps to put a period in the $_.dept :)